# Android Canvas Performance Terrible on Droid

Tags: android, performance, android-canvas

I've been developing a game for Android for the past few months, and it's just about finished. I recently acquired a Motorola Droid for testing purposes, as I developed the game using a HTC Incredible. On my Incredible I can get a pretty solid 59 fps throughout the game. On the Droid, the game becomes very choppy with an average of about 40 fps. Both phones are running Android 2.2.

I looked up the tech specs are here are the only differences I noted that might affect gameplay: 1 GHz processor vs 550 MHz and 512 MB RAM vs 256 MB RAM.

Just for giggles, I thought I would strip down the game to a very minimal state to see if it was my coding to blame. I stripped it down to the point where the only thing being down was drawing the main menu and moving various bitmaps around the screen. Not a hair over 45 fps.

So, is this the approximate cap for the Motorola Droid? If so...my game is pretty simple and non-CPU intensive, so what can I do? There are thousands of other Android games that are much more demanding than my own, yet they seem to run very smoothly.

Is it the fact that I'm using Android's built-in Canvas and not Open-GL or some other alternative? Would anybody recommend doing that?

Could somebody enlighten me to what might be my problem here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenGL ES is the way to go. Canvas is most likely implemented on top of OpenGL ES anyway, and not very efficiently by the sounds of it.

Comment: I'll have to look into that for my next game. And what do you think about AndEngine? But for the time being...I have probably spent over 100 hours on this app, so simply throwing it out the window isn't an option. Are there any alternatives besides completely starting over?

Comment: Canvas is software-only before Android 3.0.

Comment: @adamp So does that mean Canvas does not have direct access to the hardware, as OpenGL does? Thus the reason it is not as fast/powerful?

Answer (score 0):

40fps is pretty good, the human eye can only detect jerkiness when the framerate falls below 25fps. Anything above 15fps is considered 'full motion'.

If you can see jitter then it may be the game pausing while the garbage collector kicks in - you can reduce this by reducing the number of objects that you create and you should be able to see it happening by using ddms.

Other than that perhaps there is a glitch calculating the frame rate?